# display all the records from last inserted row month

Tags: mysql

Am Developing blog application. For that i Need to display initial Blog posts from recent month which i have in database table.

My table Structure is:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id   Blog_title  blog_content      date    
1      blog1      content1      19-03-2014
2      blog2      content2      02-02-2014
3      blog3      content3      01-03-2013
4      blog4      content4      16-03-2014 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From the above table i need to display the blogs which are having latest month and latest year..

Output:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id   Blog_title  blog_content      date    
1      blog1      content1      19-03-2014
4      blog4      content4      16-03-2014 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need to display only latest month and latest year records.Not all records.

Comment: ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1 ?

Comment: I edited output in my question. plz check it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE year(date)=year(CURDATE())
  AND month(date)=month(CURDATE());
```